# Unable to use local .egg-info package in Docker image

Tags: docker

I created a local package that ends in .egg-info, i creted the package with a setup.py file and did  pip install -e .
I can't create a pypi package since I have company code.

My setup looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='power_manager',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        # list any dependencies your package has
        "paho-mqtt==1.6.1"
    ],
)
```

my requirements:

```
paho-mqtt==1.6.1
git+https://github.deere.com/EPVV/ODS.git@c3ba6d5289fe05d5a60c8eab26b23ad01ff71ed6#egg=power_manager&subdirectory=power_management
```

this is my docker image:

```
# Use the Python image as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# Set the working directory within the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY ./requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY ./ /app

# Specify the command to run your Python script
CMD ["python","-u", "./main_controller.py"]
```

here main_controller.py uses the package with "import power_manager" which is the local package i want.
This is not working, i get the following error:

```
❯  docker build -t ods_main .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.148MB
Step 1/6 : FROM docker.deere.com/python:3.8-alpine
 ---> f36c9f755d28
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 44a76dc3b4a9
Step 3/6 : COPY ./requirements.txt .
 ---> 972c55049f3c
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 073cabb46b7a
Collecting power_manager
  Cloning https://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:****@github.deere.com/EPVV/ODS.git (to revision c3ba6d5289fe05d5a60c8eab26b23ad01ff71ed6) to /tmp/pip-install-zmr7tyb7/power-manager_c5bb17f18b8440729603b00733c66ec6
  ERROR: Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git' while executing command git version
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**UPDATE:**
I created a new folder without git with the package, created the

```
.egg-info package and now I dont get the link my requirements:
paho-mqtt==1.6.1
# Editable install with no version control (power-manager==0.1)
-e /home/y3qucfm/workspace/power_management
```

When I creae the docker image with pip install requirements I get this:

```
y3qucfm at root/workspace/power_management        via v3.8.10 (power-management) took 32s
❯  docker build -t testing_power_manager .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.413MB
Step 1/8 : FROM docker.deere.com/python:3.8-alpine
 ---> f36c9f755d28
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 44a76dc3b4a9
Step 3/8 : COPY ./requirements.txt .
 ---> 6319e22ee559
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 53da6ad9984f
ERROR: /home/y3qucfm/workspace/power_management is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You say local egg-info but you are trying to access a remote git url in your requirements file?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko i just updated the question, i moved out of a .git folder and stopped getting the git url but still get an error!